# Splitting a number and creating new individual columns for each number split using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-structures

Good day,

I have a data frame with a column like this, let us assume with 1000rows but here is a sample:

```
 A 
12
24
36
48
```

I wish to split the number into two separate numbers. I want the output to look like this:

```
 A    B    C
12    1    2
24    2    4
36    3    6
48    4    8
```

How can I achieve this using Pandas and Numpy? Help would be truly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `floor` and `mod`:

```
df['B'] = df['A'] // 10
df['C'] = df['A'] % 10

print (df)
    A  B  C
0  12  1  2
1  24  2  4
2  36  3  6
3  48  4  8
```

If input data are strings is possible indexing by positions by `[]`:

```
print (df['A'].apply(type))
0    <class 'str'>
1    <class 'str'>
2    <class 'str'>
3    <class 'str'>
Name: A, dtype: object

df['B'] = df['A'].str[0]
df['C'] = df['A'].str[1]
#if necessary convert all columns to integers
df = df.astype(int)
print (df)
    A  B  C
0  12  1  2
1  24  2  4
2  36  3  6
3  48  4  8
```

Comment: what if the numbers are random and are not by divisible by 12 can this still be used? @jezrael

Comment: @DeepakM - Hmmm. solution working with numbers with length `2`, else get `487` splited to `48` and `7`. It depends what need.

Comment: When I run it I get this error. `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'str' and 'int'` @jazrarel

Comment: @DeepakM - it means there are strings, use `df['A'].astype(int) // 10` and `df['A'].astype(int) % 10` first

Comment: Ah ok, I realized there were `NaNs in there. It works but is there a way to make it work negating the NaNs. That would be nice! @jezrael

Comment: @DeepakM - So there are `NaN`s ? What is expected otuput if NaNs in new columns?

Comment: Let us say it should stay NaN forms in the column... @jezrael

Comment: Ok, and `print (df['A'].apply(type))` return `string`s ? Or numbers? And for `NaN` it return `float` ?

Comment: Yes returns the new columns in float and with the NaNs. @jezrael

Comment: Sorry, to many questions What return `print (df['A'].apply(type))` ?

Comment: I just used dropna() first . But hey I had another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50833671/creating-a-new-column-with-numbers-in-pandas-to-group-with-a-column-with-existin @jezrael

Answer (score 3):

For a df that size use [`floordiv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.floordiv.html#pandas.Series.floordiv) and [`mod`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mod.html#pandas.Series.mod):

```
In[141]:
df['B'] = df['A'].floordiv(10)
df['C'] = df['A'].mod(10)
df

Out[141]: 
    A  B  C
0  12  1  2
1  24  2  4
2  36  3  6
3  48  4  8
```

There are also the `numpy` equivalents, [`np.floor_divide`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.floor_divide.html) and [`np.mod`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.mod.html):

```
In[142]:
df['B'] = np.floor_divide(df['A'],10)
df['C'] = np.mod(df['A'],10)
df

Out[142]: 
    A  B  C
0  12  1  2
1  24  2  4
2  36  3  6
3  48  4  8
```

The numpy versions are faster:

```
%%timeit
df['B'] = df['A'].floordiv(10)
df['C']= df['A'].mod(10)
1000 loops, best of 3: 733 µs per loop

%%timeit
df['B'] = np.floor_divide(df['A'],10)
df['C'] = np.mod(df['A'],10)

1000 loops, best of 3: 491 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [15]: df.A.astype(str).str.extractall(r'(.)')[0].unstack().astype(np.int8)
Out[15]:
match  0  1
0      1  2
1      2  4
2      3  6
3      4  8
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach based on splitting every character of the number treated as string:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([12, 24, 36, 48], columns=['A'])

values = df['A'].values
split = [list(str(el)) for el in values]

out = pd.DataFrame(split, columns=['B', 'C']).astype(int)
```

which gives:

```
out
   B  C
0  1  2
1  2  4
2  3  6
3  4  8
```